# How to sum column and row pixel in binary image using python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I want to sum column and row pixel in binary image like:

[integral_projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSX0O.jpg)

What should I do? Because I am confused about this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Numpy's [sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) function is the easiest and most efficient way to do this in Python.

```
import numpy as np
sumOfColumns = np.sum(yourImage, axis=0)
sumOfRows = np.sum(yourImage, axis=1)
```